# Counting Specific Word Frequency In R

Tags: r

I have a data set where I have split text from the journal abstracts to print 1 word per column. This has lead to over 5 million rows, but I just want certain the word counts of certain words. Below is an example of the data:

- 1 rna
- 1 synthesis
- 1 resembles
- 1 copy
- 1 choice
- 1 rna
- 1 recombination
- 1 process
- 1 nascent
- 1 rna

So in that example let's say I want just the rna counts, I would get 3 and that's it. I have done that word count on the whole set but this is not as useful to me.

wordCount <- m3 %>%
  count(word, sort = TRUE)

Since many of the words aren't helpful for what I am trying to get to.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Could you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @jRafi I have a data set with a column of over 5 million rows. I only need the counts of certain words within that 5 million rows worth of data. How can I go about doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `group_by` the word and count occurrences of each unique word and then subset the ones you want.

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(word = c("rna",
                "synthesis",
                "resembles",
               "copy",
                "choice",
                "rna",
                "recombination",
               "process",
                "nascent",
                "rna"))

counts <- data %>% 
  group_by(word) %>% 
  count()

counts[which(counts$word == "rna"),]

   # A tibble: 1 x 2
# Groups:   word [1]
  word      n
  <fct> <int>
1 rna       3
```

or using dplyr subsetting:

```
 counts %>% filter(word == "rna")
# A tibble: 1 x 2
# Groups:   word [1]
  word      n
  <fct> <int>
1 rna       3
```

Piping it all through at once:

```
 data %>% 
   group_by(word) %>% 
   count() %>%
   filter(word == "rna")
```

A one liner with data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[word == "rna", .N, by = word]

   word N
1:  rna 3
```